# How use JQuery $(this) in javascript Classes

Tags: jquery, oop, this

When I write jQuery code, I use `$(this)` to change element:

```
$('.classname').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('collapsed');
  // ..
});
```

Now I have are javascript class, looks like this:

```
class CabinetFormSize {
  constructor() {
    this.cabinetBTN = $(".cabinetBTN");
    this.events();
  }

  events() {
    this.cabinetBTN.click(this.toggleMenu.bind(this));
  }

  toggleMenu() {
     console.log($(this)); 
     this.cabinetBTN.toggleClass('d-none');
  }
}
```

If i write this in `toggleMenu()` I have class instance, but I need the element.

```
console.log($(this))
```

How can I use `$(this)` in `toggleMenu()` function to take element?
If i delete `bind(this)`, `console.log($(this))` work, but in this string `this.cabinetBTN.toggleClass('d-none')` i have `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleClass' of undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bind any `this` to your callback. jQuery will call your callback with the correct `this`. Like

```
this.cabinetBTN.click(this.toggleMenu);
```

When you bind `this` to a function, you're basically creating a new function with a "hard-coded" `this` value.

My solution with a working snippet:

```js
class CabinetFormSize {
  constructor() {
    this.cabinetBTN = $(".cabinetBTN");
    this.events();
  }

  events() {
    this.cabinetBTN.click(this.toggleMenu);
  }

  toggleMenu() {
    console.log($(this).text())
  }
}

new CabinetFormSize();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cabinetBTN">Click me</div>
```

Comment: But how i can add something like "this.cabinetNews.toggleClass("d-none")" in toggleMenu(). Without bind(this), i have error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleClass' of undefined' ?

Comment: What is `cabinetNews`? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: please look at question, i edit it more accurately.